# Call thirdparty module function directly from PHP in template

Tags: php, freemember, logout

I'm in a situation where I need to logout the current logged_in member without him clicking a logout link. (Javascript click trigger is not an option.)

I'm using the great freemember module (https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/)

How can I call the freemember lougout function directly from PHP in a template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<php

include PATH_THIRD . 'freemember/libraries/freemember_lib.php';

$free = new Freemember_lib();

$free->logout();

?>
```

Have you tried something like that? There's is also the `load` function attached to the EE core, but things like above usually always work for me.

Also, freemember **is** probably loaded to the core...

```
<?php ee()->freemember->logout(); ?>
```

Could work. Also, this seems likely to work as well...

```
<?php ee()->session->destroy(); ?>
```

Comment: code #1 triggers PHP error

Comment: code #2 does not work unknown property

Comment: code #3 is spot on ! (just had to add a redirect to make it work completely but that's what I needed, thanks)

Comment: Awesome! derp, the first example, lulz, I didn't instantiate the class. I'll update it, but you got something working, so success!